# Alinhando duas divs em um Modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, front-end

Estou com uma dúvida para alinhar duas divs usando o Bootstrap.

```
<div class="info-suporte col-sm-8">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><div class="foto" ></div></th>
                                    <th><div class="bloco"><p id="modal-bloco">Bloco 6</p></div></th>
                                    <th><div class="corte">Corte</div></th>
                                    <th><div class="lr">AP</div></th>
                                    <th><div class="hr">AQ</div></th>
                                    <th><div class="tar lr">AP</div></th>
                                    <th><div class="hr">AQ</div></th>
                                    <th><div class="lr">AP</div></th>
                                    <th><div class="hr">AQ</div></th>
                                    <th><div class="alta_prioridade">AP</div></th>
                                    <th><div class="alta_qualidade">AQ</div></th>
                                    <th><div class="publicacao integra">Integra</div></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr class="row-inicio">
                                    <th scope="row">Início</th>
                                    <td class="bloco"></td>
                                    <td class="cut"></td>
                                    <td class="lr"></td>
                                    <td class="hr"></td>
                                    <td class="lr"></td>
                                    <td class="hr"></td>
                                    <td class="lr"></td>
                                    <td class="hr"></td>
                                    <td class="alta_prioridade"></td>
                                    <td class="alta_qualidade"></td>
                                    <td class="pub"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="row-fim">
                                    <th scope="row">Fim</th>
                                    <td class="bloco"></td>
                                    <td class="cut"></td>
                                    <td class="lr"></td>
                                    <td class="hr"></td>
                                    <td class="lr"></td>
                                    <td class="hr"></td>
                                    <td class="lr"></td>
                                    <td class="hr"></td>
                                    <td class="alta_prioridade"></td>
                                    <td class="alta_qualidade"></td>
                                    <td class="publicacao"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="row-total">
                                    <th scope="row">Duração</th>
                                    <td class="bloco"></td>
                                    <td class="corte"></td>
                                    <td class="lr"></td>
                                    <td class="hr"></td>
                                    <td class="lr"></td>
                                    <td class="hr"></td>
                                    <td class="lr"></td>
                                    <td class="hr"></td>
                                    <td class="alta_prioridade"></td>
                                    <td class="alta_qualidade"></td>
                                    <td class="publicacao"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 sla" id='modal-sla'>
                        <div class="sla-title col-sm-12 info-suporte-badge erro">
                            <p>SLA</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sla-body col-sm-12">
                            <p >Total Previsto</p>
                            <p class="sla-time previsto"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sla-body col-sm-12">
                            <p>Total Efetivo</p>
                            <p class="sla-time efetivo"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Tentei mais não consegui alinhar essas duas `div`. A `div` com `class="col-sm-2"` fica por cima da tabela.
Vale ressaltar que elas estão em um modal e pelo o que percebi a tabela é muito grande para colocar uma ao lado da outra.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja exatamente o problema que comentou... a tabela é muito grande e ela acaba ficando maior que o tamanho da div no bootstrap... fiz um teste [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/6xt2wy8x/) e quando redimensionamos a janela podemos ver que a tabela fica por baixo... quando o item não é uma tabela, funciona ok...